# Print out entities in a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Is it possible to print out the entities in a char array so one can actually see every characters that is string terminator \0 and new line \n ... for instance?

Let say a string consists of the following

```
 abkdfkdfmdfier\nkdfdfkdkf\n\0
```

I want to see everything via std::cout

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: give me some time ...

Comment: everything - including \0 and \n

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a function that creates a new string based on the old one and changes `'\n','\0'` chars to `"\\n","\\0"` strings.

I may have some error but my main idea is this.

Ihope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *mstr;

void newStr(char *str){
   char *buf;
   if((buf=(char*)malloc(strlen(str)+4)*sizeof(char))==NULL){
      printf("err in allocating buffer");
      getch();
      exit(1);
   }
   register unsigned int i;
   for(i=0;i<strlen(str) & i<30000;i++){
      if(str[i]=='\n'){
         str[i]=0;
         strcpy(buf,"\\n");
         strcat(buf,(char*)(str+i+1));
         strcat(str,buf));
      }
   }
   strcat(str,"\\0");
}
void main(){
   clrscr();
   strcpy(mstr,"this is a\n test\nggg\0");
   printf("form1:\n%s",str);
   newStr(str);
   printf("\nform2:\n%s",str);
   getch();
}
```

Comment: Your welcome but I think the Idea is correct and you need to change it a little bit. But I don't have any compiler in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the ASCII code of a char in string.

```
for (int i=0; i<strlen(string)+1; i++) {
    if (printable(string[i])) cout << string[i];  // If normal char like abc ' ' 123 !@#
    else {
        int code = string[i];
        // i will write for '\n' for example
        switch (code) {
            case 0x0A : cout << "\\n";
                        break;
            // etc...
        }
     }
 }
```

now, `printable(char c)` would check if the ascii value is some of the printable chars (and also check if among them isn't some special char like `\0`, `\n`, etc.

http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using [isprint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) & stream formatters:

```
#include <cctype>

void print_escaped(char chr) {
    if (std::isprint(chr)) {
        std::cout << chr;
    } else {
        switch(chr) {
        case '\0': std::cout << "\\0"; break;
        case '\r': std::cout << "\\r"; break;
        case '\n': std::cout << "\\n"; break;
        case '\t': std::cout << "\\t"; break;
        default: // other non printable chars
            std::cout << "\\x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << (int)chr;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string text = "abkdfkdfmdfier\nkdfdfkdkf\n";
    text.push_back('\0'); // don't use it in a raw string !
    text.push_back('\x03');
    std::for_each(text.begin(), text.end(), print_escaped);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```